# Which way is better to populate the Dropdownlist in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I Have a List like

```
  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Users;
```

I can populate the Users Items in Dropdownlist by 3 way

1-Use ViewModel

```
Public class myViewModel
{
   IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserList;
}
```

and fill it like

```
viewmodel.UserList=GetUsers();
```

2-Use from ViewBag

```
ViewBag.UserList=GetUsers();
```

3-Use from ViewData

```
ViewData["Users"]=GetUsers();
```

What is Difference between my ways and which one is better

Comment: There is no technical difference. There is only usage difference. Strongly-Typed usage(your first exam.) is the better to check variable types at compile time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a fourth way, which I think is the best way to go.
Since you only have one object (of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`) you could just pass it to your view as the model (no need for an intermediate ViewModel).

In terms of the possibilities, there's no real difference. The difference is that your first method and the method I just described are strongly typed, meaning you get Intellisense and compile-time validation whereas your second and third method are weakly typed and you get no intellisense and no compile-time validation.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, better to use ViewModel because it's clean MVC and you get strongly-type benefits.
ViewBag and ViewData are better, for example, if you have a lot of partial views in your view, or difficult layout which need passed data. But as I understood, you need only to show dropdownlist, so use ViewModel.